# Why isn't this AngularJS 2 child @Component substituting?

Tags: angular, typescript

UPDATE: This appears to be an issue with the way I am building and serving the project (gulp, browserify, tsify, uglify) rather than a code issue.  I'll update further if I figure it out.

Thanks for the help.

I am working on an AngularJS 2 app, but I can't get the child component to substitute.  The main component "my-app" works, but the "test-view" child component doesn't get replaced.  I don't see any errors listed for the TypeScript compile, or in the browser console log.

main.ts:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

console.log('bootstraping...');
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }  from './component';
import { TestView } from './testcomponent';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, TestView ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TestView } from './TestComponent'; // EDIT

@Component({
  directives: [TestView], // EDIT
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<p>Hello World...again</p><test-view></test-view>'
})
export class AppComponent {
    my_string: string = 'Hello World';
}
```

testcomponent.ts:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'test-view',
    template: `
<p>My input: {{myInput}}</p>
    `
})
export class TestView {
    myInput: string = 'My Test Input';
}
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Here is the DOM:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will still need to declare the `TestView` as a directive in the `AppComponent`.  Like:

```
@Component({
  directives: [TestView],
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<p>Hello World...again</p><test-view></test-view>'
})
```

Comment: I updated the component.ts file to 1) import TestView, and 2) list it as a directive as shown.  It didn't change the result.

Comment: Can you update the OP to show that, so others can reference that more easily?  Also, do you get any errors in the console now?

Comment: No errors now either.  I updated the OP to show this change.  The AngularJS2 documentation doesn't show using the "directives" is this a change?

Comment: Well, you do look correct, I haven't gone back through the tutorial since RC4.  I Upgraded to RC5 and just left the `directives` property there and everything has worked so I never realized it wasn't technically required.  Also, I just went into one of my projects, and updated by removing the `directives` properties on my components that are using other components, and adding all the sub-components to the `ngModule` declaration, and it all worked fine.  What does the DOM look like in the browser?  Do you at least see the placeholder for the TestView template?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the DOM to the OP.  It replaces the parent component successfully, but doesn't replace the child.

Comment: Just as a test, can you try placing the TestView template on one line, maybe even in standard quotes, and not as a template literal?

Comment: I tried to change both templates to standard, one-line templates, and it was the same result. Thanks.